# I can't find what makes the error, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: lua, solar2d

I was following a tutorial and did exactly what it showed but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local sheetOptions = {
    width = 512,
    height = 256,
    numFrames = 8
}

local sheet_runningCat = graphics.newImageSheet( "sprites-cat-running.png", sheetOptions )

local sequences_runningCat = {
    {
        name = "normalRun",
        start = 1,
        count = 8,
        time = 800,
        loopCount = 0,
        loopDirection = "forward"
    }
}

local runningCat = display.newSprite( sheet_runningCat, sequences_runningCat )
```

It creates this error...

```
main.lua:26: bad argument #1 to 'newSprite' (ImageSheet expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'newSprite'
        main.lua:26 in main chunk
        
Do you want to relaunch the project?
```

Comment: Hint: what would cause `graphics.newImageSheet` to return nil?

Comment: Can you verify that you actually have the file 'sprites-cat-running.png' in your folder?
It seems like it can't locate this file.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the file "sprites-cat-running.png" was not found in the same directory as this file `main.lua` so `graphics.newImageSheet()` returns a nil value, and `sheet_runningCat` is now nil instead of an ImageSheet object.

To fix this, download the image file from the tutorial and save it in the same directory as `main.lua`